# "The server isn't currently responsive" error when trying to log into Unity Hub

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking

I had reinstalled Unity and Unity Hub to fix package manager error, and when I try to log into Unity Hub after it installs, i get the following error

[image]

"The server is currently unresponsive"

I tried to log in through both Google and facebook, but it didn't work (i created my account through those methods)

How do i fix this?

Comment: Okay. Do you know know how to fix this problem?

Comment: When someone has a solution to offer you, they'll post in in the Answer box below. You don't need to ask for a solution in the comments - your Question above does that already. While you wait, you can [review existing threads about troubleshooting this issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+%22server+is+currently+unresponsive%22)